# Al generar textos en JSON, los caracteres con acento se ven diferente

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas con un código creado en Python, y es que cuando genero unos textos en json, no se aprecian los acentos.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
import requests
url = requests.get(f"https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json")
summary = url.json()[0]['summary']
print(summary)
```

Este es el texto que me genera:

```
Nos estamos preparando para esos fr&#xED;os meses de invierno con unos merecidos mimos en el Onsen japon&#xE9;s.
```

Me gustaría poder corregir para que se vea los acentos.

Comment: No genera nada, así vienen en el archivo JSON que estás leyendo. Te corresponde parsear esos textos para mostrarlos. Esos son carácteres Unicode. Aplícale alguna transformación que convierta los Unicode en los carácteres correspondientes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El texto contiene caracteres codificados en entidades html

```
import requests
from html import unescape
url =  requests.get(f"https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json")
summary =  unescape(url.json()[0]['summary'])
print(summary)
```

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta. ¿Cual acción soluciona el problema? ¿Tengo que escanear el código, compararlo contra la pregunta original?

Comment: Exactamente, dado que son 5 líneas de código, eso no es ningún problema.